# Shell getopts for grabbing arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

I have a script which should be run as either one of these two:

```
script.sh -t TYPE
script.sh -t TYPE -f FILE
```

- If it is run without a `-t` flag I want it to error and exit.
- If it is run with a `-t` flag I want to grab the value and store it in a
  variable called "$TYPE" and print "JUST $TYPE"
- If it is run with a `-f` flag I want it grab the value and store it in a variable called
  "$FILE" and print "$TYPE and $FILE"

From information and tutorials on both here and the internet generally this is the closest I can get. Can anyone help me put in the second conditional into this existing code?

```
while getopts ":t:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    a)
      echo "JUST $OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Error - Invalid type argument" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
    :)
      echo "Error - No type argument" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this:

```
TYPE=""
FILE=""

while getopts "t:f:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        t)  TYPE="$OPTARG"
            ;;
        f)  FILE="$OPTARG"
            ;;
    esac
done

if [ -z "$TYPE" ]; then
  echo "No -t. Bye."
  exit 1 # error
else
  if [ -n "$FILE" ]; then
    echo "$TYPE and $FILE"
  else
    echo JUST $TYPE
  fi
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you get confused how you should handle command line arguments.

The common way is that the processing of all arguments precedes the actual job of the program/script.

Further more (related to `getopts`) if an option is appended by a colon, that indicates that the option is expected to have an argument.

Your `case` statement looks overpopulated too. You don't need to test for a colon and a question mark. The whole testing can be put after the `while` loop

---

I would do it like this

```
#!/bin/bash
unset TYPE
unset FILE

#uncomment if you want getopts to be silent
#OPTERR=0

while getopts "t:f:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    t)
      TYPE=$OPTARG
      echo "JUST $OPTARG"
      ;;
    f)
      FILE=$OPTARG
      ;;
  esac
done

if ! test "$TYPE" ; then
    echo "-t is obligatory"
    exit 1
fi

if test "$TYPE" && test "$FILE" ; then
    echo "$TYPE and $FILE"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Does this work with #!/bin/sh too?

Comment: I don't know what shell is behind `/bin/sh`, but i would try it.

Comment: Strictly speaking, no. There is an external program `getopt` that you can use to process options if your shell does not support the `getopts` command, though.